# Ubuntu Socket programming : Packets are repackaged between TX and RX

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have 2 Ubuntu 14.04 PCs. One is used as a server and the other one is used as a client. The client setup a TCP connection to the server which sends some packets back. Here's the code on the server:

send(sd, pkt, pkt_len, MSG_NOSIGNAL);

The code on the client side is also very simple:

read(sd, buf, buf_size);

If the transmissions on the server is spaced out, I don't see any issue. However, if server is doing rapid transmissions, then thing looks ugly. Here's an example when the server is sending 8 packets back-to-back.

The server code shows the size of these 8 packets are: 752 (bytes), 713, 713, 713, 396, 398, 396, 396

tcpdump on the server captures 4 TX packets: 752 (bytes), 1398, 1398, 929

tcpdump on the client captures 3 RX packets: 752 (bytes), 2796, 929

The client code shows it receives only 2 packets with 3548 bytes and 929 bytes, respectively.

So you can see all the bytes sent by the server are received by the client. However, packets are combined at various points in the transmission path. I guess this is due to TSO, GSO, GRO, etc. However, shouldn't these optimizations re-assemble the packets back to the correct form when the packets are delivered to the receiving application?

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Note that it's not that packets are combined at various points in the transmission path, but rather that the sizes of the byte-sequences you get out of each recv() call are unrelated to the size of the network packets.

Comment: The answer is to use UDP instead of TCP because TCP is a streaming protocol. You should not rely in any way on the server or the client how packets will be received because there is no such thing as a packet. It is a continuous stream of bytes that just may happen to be received in the way you experienced because of the delay you imposed yourself which influences the behavior of the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

TCP is carefully designed to not only permit but implement exactly what you're seeing. It is a byte-stream protocol. If you want messages you have to implement them yourself via a superimposed application protocol.

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, there are ways to change the way your kernel treats TCP packets, such as disabling the Nagle algorithm and enabling SO_LINGER. This doesn't change how other routers treat the same packets, though.

Comment: @slushie SO_LINGER has nothing to do with it whatsoever, and the Nagle algorithm is only part of the issue.

Comment: and that's why your answer is correct, because Nagle only applies within the kernel. Alternatively, he could use UDP and sacrifice reliability.

Comment: Nagle disables a 50ms timeout that TCP uses to try to fill up to the mtu before sending a segment. If this user would send segments of more than the mtu he would have complained that his original message is fragmented. And then this has not much to do with nagle.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get around this issue?

So you're using TCP (a byte-stream-oriented transport mechanism) but you'd like it to have message-oriented behavior.  You can't change the way TCP works (it is, by design, allowed to transport bytes in whatever-sized groups it chooses to, as long as the bytes are all received and they are received in the same order).  But you can add a layer on top of TCP to simulate packet-oriented behavior.

For example, say you wanted to simulate the transmission of a 1000-byte "packet".  Your sending program could first send out a fixed-size (let's say, 4-byte) header that would tell the receiver how many bytes the "packet" will contain:

```
size_t myPacketSize = 1000;  // or whatever the size of your packet is 
uint32_t bePacketSize = htonl(myPacketSize);  // convert native-endian to big-endian for cross-platform compatibility
if (send(sd, &bePacketSize, sizeof(bePacketSize), 0) != sizeof(bePacketSize)) 
{
    perror("send(header)");
}
```

.... then right after that you'd send out the packet's payload data:

```
if (send(sd, packetDataPtr, myPacketSize, 0) != myPacketSize) 
{
    perror("send(body)");
}
```

The receiver would need to receive the header/size value, then allocate an array of that size and receive the payload data into it.  Since this code has to handle the incoming data correctly no matter how many bytes are returned by each recv() call, it's a little more complex than the sending code:

```
void HandleReceivedPseudoPacket(const char * packetBytes, uint32_t packetSizeBytes)
{
   // Your received-packet-handling code goes here
}

// Parses an incoming TCP stream of header+body data back into pseudo-packets for handling
void ReadPseudoPacketsFromTCPStreamForever(int sd)
{
   uint32_t headerBuf;               // we'll read each 4-byte header's bytes into here
   uint32_t numValidHeaderBytes = 0; // how many bytes in (headerBuf) are currently valid

   char * bodyBuf = NULL;          // will be allocated as soon as we know how many bytes to allocate
   uint32_t bodySize;              // How many bytes (bodyBuf) points to
   uint32_t numValidBodyBytes = 0; // how many bytes in (bodyBuf) are currently valid
   while(1)
   {
      if (bodyBuf == NULL)
      {
         // We don't know the bodySize yet, so read in header bytes to find out
         int32_t numBytesRead = recv(sd, ((char *)&headerBuf)+numValidHeaderBytes, sizeof(headerBuf)-numValidHeaderBytes, 0);
         if (numBytesRead > 0)
         {
            numValidHeaderBytes += numBytesRead;
            if (numValidHeaderBytes == sizeof(headerBuf))
            {
               // We've read the entire 4-byte header, so now we can allocate the body buffer
               numValidBodyBytes = 0;
               bodySize = ntohl(headerBuf);  // convert from big-endian to the CPU's native-endian
               bodyBuf = (char *) malloc(bodySize);
               if (bodyBuf == NULL)
               {
                  perror("malloc");
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
         else if (numBytesRead < 0)
         {
            perror("recv(header)");
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            printf("TCP connection was closed while reading header bytes!\n");
            break;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         // If we got here, then we know the bodySize and now we need to read in the body bytes
         int32_t numBytesRead = recv(sd, &bodyBuf[numValidBodyBytes], bodySize-numValidBodyBytes, 0);
         if (numBytesRead > 0)
         {
            numValidBodyBytes += numBytesRead;
            if (numValidBodyBytes == bodySize)
            {
                // At this point the pseudo-packet is fully received and ready to be handled
                HandleReceivedPseudoPacket(bodyBuf, bodySize);

                // Reset our state variables so we'll be ready to receive the next header
                free(bodyBuf);
                bodyBuf = NULL;
                numValidHeaderBytes = 0;
            }
         }
         else if (numBytesRead < 0)
         {
            perror("recv(body)");
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            printf("TCP connection was closed while reading body bytes!\n");
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   // Avoid memory leak if we exited the while loop in the middle of reading a psuedo-packet's body
   if (bodyBuf) free(bodyBuf);
}
```